# Cannot access internal components from test source with Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have got the following structure:

```
build.gradle
src
 - main
   - AndroidManifest.xml
   - kotlin 
     - pkg
       - MyClass.kt (internal class MyClass)
 - test
   - kotlin
     - pkg
       - MyClassTest.kt
```

In `MyClassTest.kt` I reference the `internal class MyClass`.

---

The `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

  sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
  }
}

dependencies {
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-2423'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Now when I run `./gradlew test`, I get the following error:

> Cannot access 'MyClass': it is 'internal' in 'pkg'

However, when I switch the plugins to use `java` instead of `com.android.application`, and `kotlin` instead of `kotlin-android`, the tests do succeed.

How can I reference internal classes from my test sources when using the Android plugins?

Comment: This is a bug in the Gradle plugin for Kotlin, a fix is almost ready, will be included with the next Beta update.

Comment: Ah, cool. Is there an issue on YouTrack for this?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9441

Comment: KT-9441 has been marked as Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue existed as bug [KT-9441](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9441) (as noted by @Andrey), and has since been fixed.  There should be no current problem with latest Kotlin and its Gradle plugins.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue for Android projects? Using version 1.0.1.

Comment: It was a fix in both Intellij IDEA and Kotlin plugin working together, therefore the Android studio build could be an older version of Intellij IDEA which has the issue.

Comment: I'm also struggling with exactly same issue in Android (Android Studio), with kotlin version '1.0.1-2'. Is it possible that this depends on the IDE?

Comment: @MarcinBak For bugs, it is best to use https://youtrack.jetbrains.com instead of StackOverflow, as you can add comments and notes to the reported bug, see status, and receive help more directly.